# python : Any use of this assignment to an empty list?

Tags: python, scipy

Example code form [scipy document](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm):

```
from scipy.stats import norm
numargs = norm.numargs
[  ] = [0.9,] * numargs
rv = norm()
```

I am totally confused about what is the third line doing here. Could any one explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I call shenanigans on this. So `numargs` has type `int` and this code will fail if it is anything other than `0`. Essentially this code is just `[]=[]` which to me would seem utterly pointless.

It may be just a relic from the docs, as the following crops up elsewhere:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import nct
>>> numargs = nct.numargs
>>> [ df, nc ] = [0.9,] * numargs
>>> rv = nct(df, nc)
```

Perhaps the examples were auto generated. As all the other distributions examples have a similar format.

Comment: Auto generated. Reasonable!